# Netbeans project cannot add server

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat7

I'm newbie in Java Programming, I have a project with Tomcat Server, but when I have my Tomcat Server Run, the project can't be execute because "the target server has not been set or has been removed..."
but my Tomcat Server has been run well and that project can't catch my tomcat server. What the solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your system already has the tomcat server - then do the following -

Check first which server is associated in your project - [Based on Netbeans 8.0.2]

1. Right-click the on the project from the project panel and choose Projects  Properties at the bottom option
2. Select Run from the Project Properties.
3. The very first option is **Server**. check which Server it is included in your project. You can change your server from the dropdown list. 
   [image]

Another option to add the **Tomcat** or any other server -

1. Choose Tools > Servers
2. At the Bottom you have option to Add Server.
3. Or you can change from there if your system have other available server.
4. You can change port also
   [image]